# Combining two "1D vertical" dataframes into a "2D" dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to submit a data column into a signal processing engine that requires a timestamp with each row of data. Picture two columns in Excel - calculated timestamp in the left column and data in the right column. So I now have two dataframes that are each 1 cell by 27k cells long. The data doesn't have a common key between them so they don't need to be aligned. How can I combine them into a single "two column wide by 27k rows long" dataframe?

Comment: look into `pandas.concat`

Answer (score 0):

The objects that you have at the moment, are they DataFrames or Series? (Series is a signle column of a DataFrame).

If they are DataFrames with a single column, then you would need to put them in a list and use pd.concat():

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

If they are actually Series (s1 and s2), then you can just create a DataFrame from it that will have both columns:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Date': s1, 'Vals': s2})
```